# How to rotate a view like opening door?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-spinner, objectanimator

I want to create a layout that will contain some spinner for selecting value from list.

**Working:** When I click on spinner the Layout should be rotate like opening door and list of values should be appear from left edge of screen. After selecting a value from list the Layout should be rotate again and look like closing door and list of values should go to left edge of screen and selected value should be appear on spinner.

**Image Link:** https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=2CC6E5A8B70750DE&id=2CC6E5A8B70750DE!751&authkey=!AIu144d4FjBpiVc&v=3

(I am providing a screen shot of iPhone having desired layout. I can't upload image on stackoverflow so I am giving image URL.)

Thanks in advance.

**Activity Layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llRegistration"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:background="#1AA0B0"
android:gravity="left" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnState"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select One" />
```

**Object Animator (flip_on_vertical.xml)**

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="1000"
android:propertyName="rotationY"
android:valueFrom="0"
android:valueTo="50"
android:valueType="floatType" >
```

**Code**

```
 LinearLayout linearLayoutRegistration;
 Button btnSelect;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_new);

    linearLayoutRegistration = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llRegistration);
    btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnState);
    btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            flipOnVertical(linearLayoutRegistration);
        }
    });
}

public void flipOnVertical(View view) {
    View image = findViewById(view.getId());

    Animator anim = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this,
            R.animator.flip_on_vertical);
    anim.setTarget(image);
    anim.start();

}
```

Comment: post `flip_on_vertical`

Comment: I have posted filp_on_vertical.xml